# Filtering Datagrid by Category

Tags: c#, datagrid, filter

So i have a Datagrid which populates with data from a text file, the data is about pictures, there are file names etc, one of the Fields is category.

A list of all of these objects is Bound to the data grid.

```
            var source = new BindingSource();

            source.DataSource = images;

            dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
```

what i want to do is when i click my Filter button it will take the user input in lets say from the Category filter text box  and only show the records with that Category.

Even if only get pointed in the right direction it would be nice, but i have searched around  cant find a solution that works for me.

Comment: I think, what i would do, before i bind my data to the grid view, i would have a loop that would only bind data that is filtered. Just a random thought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a list you can doing something like this to filter the category to return only "categoryA" items:

```
string myfilter = "categoryA";

var MyFilteredList = MyList.Where(item => item.category == myfilter);

datagridView1.DataSource = MyFilteredList;
datagridView1.Databind();
```